# Not able to scroll an image Horizontally when zoomed in windows phone 8.1 U1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

i have not able to achieve horizontally scroll zoomed image...  vertical zoom is successful using this Xaml... Kindly help solving horizontal scroll of a zoomed image FOR windows phone 8.1 u1...

REGARDS

```
enter code here <Page
x:Class="Bus_Time.BasicPage1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Bus_Time"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- Title Panel -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="19,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page title" Margin="0,-6.5,0,26.5" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" CharacterSpacing="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid Margin="0,8.833,0,10" Grid.Row="1">
        <ScrollViewer   ZoomMode="Enabled"  MinZoomFactor="0.8" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
            <StackPanel Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Orientation="Vertical"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image Source="Assets/Image1/0001.jpg"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="350" Width="380"/>
                <Image Source="Assets/Image1/0002.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="350" Width="300"/>
                <Image Source="Assets/Image1/0003.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="350" Width="380"/>
                <Image Source="Assets/Image1/0004.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="350" Width="380"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the content doesn't fit in your ScrollViewer? Width of the images is 380, that's less than a page size for Windows and Windows Phone alike.

Anyway, you can try setting `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` to `Auto` or `Visible`.

Comment: image can be zoomed and scrolled horizontally...but once zoomed IN and  horizontal scroll is performed, the image doesn't stay in the same position..it will automatically scroll back in the opposite way...for example if I zoom IN and perform Left scroll the image doesn't stay there...it will automatically right scrolled...